# Cannot convert undefined or null to object typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wrote a pipe but when I using the pipe gives an error

**HTML**

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let officer of companies?.officers | valueArray" label="{{officer.name}}">
```

**TS**

```
    import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'valueArray',
})
export class ValueArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(objects: any = []): any {
    return Object?.values(objects);
  }
}
```

Comment: And what's the error? Don't keep secrets ;D

Comment: Cannot convert undefined or null to object )))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`null-coalescing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`) operator to use a default value if is `null` or `undefined`.

Setting a default value for a function argument only works when nothing is passed for that argument into the function, so that should be why your default `[]` value doesn't work.

```
...
  transform(objects: any = []): any {
    return Object.values(objects ?? {});
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try accounting for the fact that the input parameter for the transform method can also be `null` or `undefined`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'valueArray',
})
export class ValueArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(objects: any = []): any {
    if (!objects) {
      return null; // or [], or undefined
    }
    return Object.values(objects);
  }
}
```